# .htaccess detect "/logged-in" at end of any URL and redirect to same URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'd like to know how to create a .htaccess rewrite rule that can check for "/logged-in" at the end of any pretty URL, and then pass a GET parameter back to that same page.

Essentially the user can log in on any page, then the page reloads with /logged-in attached to it. I need to run some PHP that checks:

```
if ($_GET['mode'] == 'logged-in')
```

to display a modal on the page they were on confirming the login.

It can be any page on the site, any level deep.

So an example URL might be:

```
www.domain.com/shop/category-id/logged-in
```

which would need to rewrite to:

```
www.domain.com/shop/category-id/?mode=logged-in
```

Obviously the above URL is already being rewritten prior to this as it is actually loading:

```
www.domain.com/shop/category.php?id=category-id
```

So essentially need to know how to detect:

```
*/logged-in
```

and get back to

```
*/?mode=logged-in
```

while keeping the URL pretty.

Here are the current rewrite rules. ALL of these need to also support placing /logged-in at the end of them, and I was hoping I wouldn't have to manually make a new rewrite rule for each one.

```
# BLOG
RewriteRule ^blog/page/([0-9]+)/?$    blog.php?page=$1     [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    blog.php?cat=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    blog-post.php?cat=$1&url=$2    [NC,L]

# SHOP API
RewriteRule ^shop/cart/add/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)?/?$    shop/?mode=add2cart&id=$1&sku=$2    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/cart/update/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$    shop/?mode=updatecartitemcount&id=$1&sku=$2&count=$3    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/cart/remove/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$    shop/?mode=updatecartitemcount&id=$1&sku=$2&count=0    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/(generate_token)/?$    shop/?mode=$1   [NC,L]    
RewriteRule ^shop/(get_details)/([0-9]+)/?$    shop/?mode=$1&id=$2    [NC,L]

# SHOP
RewriteRule ^shop/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    shop/category.php?cat=$1    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^shop/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    shop/category.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^shop/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9-_]+)?/?$    shop/product.php?cat=$1&url=$2&id=$3    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^policies/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    policy.php?url=$1    [NC,L]

# CHECKOUT
RewriteRule ^checkout/(review)?/?$    checkout/index.php?view=review    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^checkout/(checkout|payment|complete)/?$    checkout/index.php?view=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^checkout/load/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    checkout/index.php?mode=load_content&view=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^checkout/(redeem_coupon|get_total|generate_token)/?$    checkout/index.php?mode=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^checkout/update_shipping/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$     checkout/index.php?mode=update_shipping&view=$1&country=$2&shipping_type=$3    [NC,L]

# USER ACCOUNTS
RewriteRule ^account/order/([0-9-_]+)/?$    view-order.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^account/order/([0-9-_]+)/print-invoice/?$    view-order.php?id=$1&mode=print-invoice    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^account/update/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    account.php?mode=update&section=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^forgot-my-password/submit/?$    forgot-my-password.php?mode=submit    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^update-password/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    forgot-my-password.php?hash=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^update-password/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/submit/?$    forgot-my-password.php?mode=reset-password&hash=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^register/submit/?$    index.php?mode=register    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^login/submit/?$    index.php?mode=login    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$    index.php?mode=logout     [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^logged-out/?$    index.php?mode=logged-out    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^subscribe/?$    index.php?mode=newsletter-subscribe    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^confirm/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    index.php?mode=newsletter-confirm&code=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^confirm-account/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    index.php?mode=account-confirm&code=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact/submit/?$     contact.php?mode=submit    [NC,L]

# SEARCH RESULTS
RewriteRule ^search/?([A-Za-z0-9-_+]+)?/?$    search-results.php?query=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-_+]+)/(render_results)/?$    search-results.php?query=$1&mode=$2     [NC,L]
```

Scott

Comment: I don't actually have a .htaccess rule for this yet - hence me wondering how to do it!

Comment: That's done now. I have added all the rules that power this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)/(logged-in)/?$ $1?mode=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# all your rules go below this line
```